# Strange behavior of StampedLock with Thread class

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, stampedlock

I'm running this code in IntellijIDEA Community on Windows

```
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();
        Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
            long stamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();
            try {
                System.out.println("Optimistic Lock Valid: " + lock.validate(stamp));
                sleep(1);
                System.out.println("Optimistic Lock Valid: " + lock.validate(stamp));
                sleep(2);
                System.out.println("Optimistic Lock Valid: " + lock.validate(stamp));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            } finally {
                lock.unlock(stamp);
            }
        });

        th.start();
        try {
            th.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the valid output, but with the `IllegalMonitorStateException`

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Users\izotova\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=54575:C:\Users\izotova\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\izotova\Documents\case-study-java-backend\Tasks\out\production\tasks" Main
Optimistic Lock Valid: true
Optimistic Lock Valid: true
Optimistic Lock Valid: true
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlock(StampedLock.java:609)
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:22)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I honestly have no ideas, what could cause this, the stamp and lock are fine, no idea, what I'm doing incorrectly. Maybe you have some ideas or insights about how stamped locks work internally?

Comment: Just thinking about optimistic locks in general, I don't think they need to be unlocked typically.  Perhaps that is the issue?  Also you should be testing the return value, 0 indicates the lock was not acquired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to double down on the guess in my comment above and say that I don't think that optimistic locks can be unlocked (or need to be).

Here is an example pulled straight from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) of `StampedLock`.  Notice that in the unlock portion of the code they are careful to call `unlock()` only if the stamp has been upgraded from an optimistic lock to a read lock.  The example does NOT try to unlock if the lock is still an optimistic lock.

```
   // a read-only method
   // upgrade from optimistic read to read lock
   double distanceFromOrigin() {
     long stamp = sl.tryOptimisticRead();
     try {
       retryHoldingLock: for (;; stamp = sl.readLock()) {
         if (stamp == 0L)
           continue retryHoldingLock;
         // possibly racy reads
         double currentX = x;
         double currentY = y;
         if (!sl.validate(stamp))
           continue retryHoldingLock;
         return Math.hypot(currentX, currentY);
       }
     } finally {
       if (StampedLock.isReadLockStamp(stamp))
         sl.unlockRead(stamp);
     }
   }
```

Comment: It is counterintuitive, but tryOptimisticRead does not do lock at all (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.java#l511):

    public long tryOptimisticRead() {
        long s;
        return (((s = state) & WBIT) == 0L) ? (s & SBITS) : 0L;
    }