# How exactly does the tryOptimisticRead() method of the StampedLock class work?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, locks, stampedlock

I am working on the following codes.

CreateThread.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
class CreateThread
{   
   public static void main(String[] args)   
   {        
      StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();         
      MyThread[] t = new MyThread[5];       
      for(int i=0; i<2; i++)        
      {         
        t[i] = new MyThread("t"+i, lock);       
      }     
      for(int i=0; i<2; i++)        
      {         
         t[i].start();      
      } 
    }
}
```

MyThread.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
public class MyThread extends Thread
{ 
   StampedLock lock = null;    
   public MyThread(String name, StampedLock lock)    
   {    
     super(name);   
     this.lock=lock;    
    }     
    public void run()    
    {       
       long stamp = 0;
       stamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();        
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" applied for Lock "+ stamp);
       if(lock.validate(stamp))
       {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" got Lock "+ lock);
       }
       try      
       {            
         Thread.sleep(5000);        
       }        
       catch(InterruptedException e){}      
       lock.unlock(stamp);      
     }
}
```

Output:

```
t1 applied for Lock 256
t0 applied for Lock 256
t0 got Lock java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock@1ce4c0a1[Unlocked]
t1 got Lock java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock@1ce4c0a1[Unlocked]
Exception in thread "t0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlockRead(StampedLock.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlock(StampedLock.java:738)
    at MyThread.run(MyThread.java:24)
Exception in thread "t1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlockRead(StampedLock.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock.unlock(StampedLock.java:738)
    at MyThread.run(MyThread.java:24)
```

It seems that both threads never got read lock. How does this method work?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Strange behavior of StampedLock with Thread class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821239/strange-behavior-of-stampedlock-with-thread-class).

Answer (score 1):

tryOptimisticRead indeed does no locking. Use the method readLock for that.
You can use tryOptimisticRead to check if some other thread changed something inside the lock using validate. You do not need to unlock something since you did not lock anything

Comment: Thanks. But what if a writer comes in the picture after a reader just validated the previous stamp found it true but after that preempted by scheduler?

Comment: The idea is to read everything into local variables. Then validate and make your calculation using the local variables. So you make sure that you read consistent value. Of coursr after the validation another writer might update the fields but you still work on consistent but probably not the newest values.